# Is there a lower bound on the Euler characteristic of a four-manifold with given fundamental group?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Given a compact closed simply connected 4-manifold $X$ we know that $\chi(X) \geq 2$ with equality if and only if $X$ is a homotopy sphere.  Given a finitely presented group $G$, is there a lower bound on the Euler characteristic that a compact closed connected $4$-manifold with fundamental group $G$ can have?

Comment: What did you try? Poincare duality?

Comment: @MoisheCohen  In the case where $X$ is oriented then $\chi(X) = 2 + b_2 - 2g \geq 2-2g$ where $g$ is the rank of the abelianization of $G$ - but can we always realize $G$ with $b_2 = 0$?

Comment: Not in general. Read https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307101.pdf and references therein.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Perfect - thanks!